# TestFlight beta-testing iOS app

Tags: ios, testing, xcode4.3, testflight

I completed to develop my first app. Right now i want to distribute my beta throught https://testflightapp.com

I tried to create .ipa file with this tutorial - http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4

In the very beginning i should select Entitlements, but there is not such category as Code Signing..

Any helps? Thnx.

PS I have a developer account.

UPD. Does somebody create ipa files for TestFlight on XCode 4.3? How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I skipped entitlements altogether. With Xcode 4.2 and later I have not needed them.

Make sure your Archive Scheme uses your Debug configuration.  Then just do an Archive of the project (under the Product menu).  Save the Archive someplace.  Then drag that Archive file onto the TestFlightApp's green "Upload Build" button.  That easy.  No messing around with entitlements, etc.

Before you do this, make sure you can actually build a correctly formed archive by building, and e-mailing it to one of your testers and see if it can be loaded.  There are a bunch of things that have to work before you can use TestFlightApp.   Just because you can Build and Run from Xcode doesn't mean that it will work on a remote device that doesn't already have your provisioning file.  For example, you have to have your App ID, provisioning profiles and Device ID's all configured correctly via the [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action).  Once I did that, and verified that my .ipa files can be installed manually, then just uploading to TestFlightApp.com worked without having to do entitlements.

I wrote this up and put it on TestFlightApp's support forum, but for some reason TestFlightApp.com won't let me into the support area so I can find it - I can't use my login to access their "Tender" account.

Comment: So for TestFlightApp you need to get the actual AdHoc distribution right first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282810/how-to-configure-a-xcode-project-for-beta-testing-with-testflightapp

Comment: Yes, it has to be built (archived) for adhoc distribution.  I'll give you some details on your link.

Answer (score 1):

That's because that tuturial was done for another version of Xcode.

Just create a new property list file (Entitlements.plist) in your Xcode project and it let you edit it as a Entitlements file just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The [What's New in Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/WhatsNewXcode.pdf) (pdf) documentation states that:

> The iOS platform has supported entitlements for a while, and with Lion, Mac OS X does as well. With Xcode 4.1, the project editor provides a UI for setting up entitlements for Mac OS X applications. You can set entitlements for each target in the project editor. There is also a default code-signing entitlements file available in the file templates in the utilities pane.

In the Summary tab of your project editor is a section titled Entitlements. Check the "Enable Entitlements" box to have Xcode automatically create an Entitlements plist for you. This section also governs the entitlements' interaction with iCloud and Keychain.

[image: enabling entitlements]