# iOS app crashes on customer device, how to react, collect data

Tags: iphone, ios

The application crashed at the customer device. Unfortunately the app does not provide 
an error log in order to identify the root cause.

I was wondering what information can be collected from the customer device in order to start
working on the issue. For example is there a core file available? What other data might help us understand the problem?

Two cases:

1. the customer can give the device to the developer
2. the customer cannot give the device to the developer

Comment: This may help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753643/testflight-beta-testing-ios-app/9753928

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Malke the Customer get the crash log(using iTunes), search a tutorial on google about how to do it. When you have import in Xcode organizer and match it with the archive that you distribute. You shoul see a comprehensible crash log.

[Tecnote Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: is there a URL that provides the info you provided?

Answer (score 0):

We're using test flight. Test flight installs its own exception handler which provides some decent data when debugging crashes (backtrace, device type, ios version, etc.).

Comment: I cannot modify the app right now. Test flight mandates recompilation

Answer (score 0):

You can see the logs on the device:

```
Settings -> General -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostics & Usage Data
```

Answer (score 0):

While giving the customer the IPA and provision file also give him the .dSYM file and also send him step by step procedure to send back the crash logs through iTunes. That will help you find where exactly your app is crashing.